# PKAddPassButton is not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, applepay, wallet

I have a project in which I put a UIButton on a screen and changed its custom class to `PKAddPassButton` using XCode (Interface builder)
The documentation of this class said that

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0) @interface PKAddPassButton : UIButton
```

which means that it's available on iOS 9 upward.
But the app crashes every time I ran it on iOS 9 (real devices and simulators) with error message

```
This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:
```

When I ran it on iOS 10, it works fine, the button showed up.

Did anyone experience the same thing and found a solution?

Update:
The button works fine if it is created programmatically in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate it programmatically instead. That's what I did and it worked for me.